# Prestashop 1.7 Dropdown Menu Items Formatting

Tags: css, themes, prestashop, stylesheet, prestashop-1.7

**Prestashop 1.7.5 - https://alohacanary.com**
**Issue** - Drop Down Menu showing correctly in all browsers except in IExplorer

Categories should appear side by side - instead appear as a long list in IExplorer.

**Probable Cause** - @media in CSS

**What have I done so far?**

```
@media screen\0, @media screen\9 {  

.top-menu .sub-menu {
width: auto;
min-width: auto;
}
```

As issue is only in IE11 & Edge - I used - @media screen\0, @media screen\9 *(not using this is causing the dropdown to be a long list on all other browsers as well)*

Setting width and min-width to auto - helped the white background of the dropdown menu to be in line with the text in IE11 **but NOT IN EDGE**

Not sure how to proceed to solve for all IE+Edge browsers.

[image: Correct Display]

[image: Incorrect Display]
Thanks!